# JPA entity set default value from Properties

Tags: java, jpa

I have a requirement to set default for a column in entity from properties file **before persisting** and also while retrieving form DB if null do the same. On note, without changing any database column definition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need jpa callback methods like:

> @PrePersist @PreUpdate and @PostLoad

Comment: Exactly, however I foresee a problem getting the data from the properties file into the entity, since the callbacks do not have any way of bringing additional information (unless you use static, which you should never do). Do you have a good solution for that @Eugene?

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek that's possible, but not *entirely easy* I admit. http://jblewitt.com/blog/?p=129

Comment: I have tried all three solutions listed in the blog, and they are all bad solutions in my opinion. If you use EclipseLink you can customise the Entity instantiation policy, this allows you to create a factory with access to the Spring context, so you to set or Autowire fields. I don't know if Hibernate allow the same degree of customisation.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek I am not aware of such a thing in hibernate to be honest. And I agree with your opinion here...